# Anyone using a SD 702 with a SD mixer?

Tags: 702, sound-devices, mixer, gear, equipment

Just ordered a 702 for sfx recording and was wondering if anyone else finds it helpful to pair it with a mixer.  It seems slightly unnecessary although I know it could be useful for certain applications.  I am recording with a M/S setup.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The 702 has a built in MS matrix which is highly flexible.  You can decode to your headphones or to "tape".  You shouldn't need it if you are just recording 2 channels.  That said, I often use the my Sound Devices MP-2 (which has been replaced by the Mix Pre) for channels 3 and 4 on my 744T and I actually find the pres a little more pleasing.

Michael Raphael
http://rabbitearsaudio.com
http://sepulchra.com/blog/

Comment: Hey Michael,
I'm a big fan of your work and your "Rockets" SFX Library is definitely on my next purchase list...  I'm aware of the selectable M/S decoding features which is why I love the 702.  I guess I was wondering what the advantages are of having a mixer besides being able to trim levels while stuck in a menu and stuff like that. 

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Michael: A 702 for mid-side is enough. That's exactly what I use. The only reason you'd really need a mixer is to mix in more channels or to have better ergonomics and immediacy for riding levels. There are a lot of other reasons to have a 2+ channel SD mixer lying around (pairing with small hand-held recorders like the PCM-D50 or H4n, etc.), but not for what you're aiming to do!

Comment: Hey NoiseJockey, I'm a big fan of your work and your blog as well!!  Your blog definitely gets my creative juices flowing sometimes when I need a boost.  I figured that there wasn't really much of an advantage just wanted to see if I was overlooking something.  I wasn't sure if menu jockeying was required when the channels are linked to adjust levels when in M/S mode.

Comment: Oh. @bpert, sorry for not getting into that detail: Nope, you just use the two channel gain pots to control the level (L channel) and spread (R channel). Super easy, and you can either record in L-R, decoding in the box, or just monitor in MS and then translate to L-R in post. I've found it to be very fast operation and super easy.

Comment: So there isn't a need to go back to the channel inputs to balance the levels?  I assume you are controlling the gain directly in m/s mode even though they are called level and spread?  Sorry just don't have too much experience recording in M/S.  I just know that I love how it sounds.

Comment: The control of each channel's gain is done with rotary pots - KNOBS - and not with the menu. The menu affords some additional input sensitivity at a gross level, but 98% of the levels tweaking is done with the two gain knobs on the 702's front panel. In mid-side, the left channel (cardioid mic) determines overall level and the right channel (figure-8 mics) determines the amount of stereo image spread. Your question was whether or not you needed "menu jockeying" to control the levels live when in mid-side mode, and the answer is no. No need for an external mixer in that workflow!

Comment: @noisejockey do you know if the pre-amps are better than the 702's? If so, by a lot? 

Comment: @Andrew Sptiz.  I don't think by a lot.  Both are quiet but there is a little more color in the MP-2  . . . not much but a little.

Comment: @bpert -- I actually often set it up so the channels are linked, but not decoded.  And just use the pot on channel 1.  You are pretty much guaranteed a recording in phase and side levels that are relative to the mid if what you are shooting is on-axis  